# drupal commerce multiple products on one page

Tags: commerce

I'm building a website in which people can reserve plays(theater). I'm using a product display for this.

The problem is, a specific 'play' is going on for a number of days, and people should be able to reserve for a specific day.

For example : a specific play might go on the 18th,19th, and 20th of September and customers need to be able to select a date from those available.

How can this be achieved with Drupal Commerce ?

One idea I had was to create multiple products with the specific date, but how do I show multiple products on one product display ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Product Display field setup a multivalued  entity reference field of type 'node'. Now as per your example

1. you add a product for date 18, in reference field add reference to other dates as well.
2. For all dates will have reference to each other.
3. Now with view create a block display to show related nodes using relationship on reference field and take node id from context filter.
4. Put this block on product display page so it can take node id from context and show related products.

Answer (score 0):

[Commerce Attributes Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_attributes_date)

> This module provides the ability to use date field type as Product
>   Attributes.

Add date as an attribute to the Product. The product display will then have a select list (or radio buttons) where the user can select the date. That way prices can be different on different days and I'm confident that stock control (limited space for event) can be done.